# Find the mode of the Weibull distribution

Tags: weibull-distribution, mode

I am using the matlab curve fitting tool. It allows to use the Weibull distribution, using this formula:

$$f(x)=abx^{b-1}\exp(-ax^b). $$

Unfortunately this is not the formula that I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution). Can you give me the formula to calculate the mode, starting from the above mentioned formula?

Comment: Use Calculus to maximize $\log f$ by finding the zeros of its derivative $d(\log f(x))/dx = (b-1)/x - a x^b.$ That's an easy algebraic problem. As always,you will also need to check the endpoints of the domain, which in this case are $0$ and $\infty.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you substitute

$$ k=b\quad\text{and}\quad\lambda=\frac{1}{a^{\frac{1}{b}}}, $$

then your PDF formula turns into the one at Wikipedia, so you can use the formula for the mode there. It is

$$ \lambda\bigg(\frac{k-1}{k}\bigg)^\frac{1}{k}
=  \frac{1}{a^{\frac{1}{b}}}\bigg(\frac{b-1}{b}\bigg)^\frac{1}{b}$$

if $k=b>1$, and $0$ if $k=b\leq 1$.